# iOS POST request using NSURLSession

Tags: ios, post, nsurlsession

I'm trying to send a simple POST request in iOS to test a server I've written. My code is as follows:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/createUser"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    NSString *bodyData = @"username=johndoe";
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    request.HTTPBody = [bodyData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    request.timeoutInterval = 5;
    [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"resp: %@, err: %@", response, error);
    }];
```

I've been trying to debug this and am very confused. The code inside the completionHandler is never run, the request never times out, and the server never sees anything. Nothing seems to happen at all. I was able to do a request using the old `NSURLConnection` but would like to avoid that since it's deprecated. What's the issue here?

Comment: Are you trying to send a POST or a GET? The code you shared is using GET

Comment: My mistake- copy/paste error after I messed with that. I'm trying to send a POST. Fixed my code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to setting up your code to do a GET when you say you want to do a POST (as josemando points out in his comment), you're not starting your task.

You need to change your last line like this:

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] 
  dataTaskWithRequest: request 
  completionHandler: ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)    
  {
    NSLog(@"resp: %@, err: %@", response, error);
  }];
[task resume];
```

(dataTaskWithRequest creates and returns a data task object which you then have to submit for execution with the resume method.)

Comment: Thanks. I changed my code to reflect that and am still getting nothing- if the request is getting sent at all I should at least get a timeout after 5 seconds, but that's not happening.

Comment: Oops. I feel like an idiot- I was debugging by setting a breakpoint and stepping through, and execution was halted until I continued. This worked fine. Thank you.